# Ler arquivo TXT com PHP e gravar no mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo para controle do equipamento da empresa, consigo gerar um log do equipamento com todas as informações referentes ao equipamento, porém este arquivo não é tabulado, exemplo abaixo de algumas linhas:

```
SET SYS:SYSDESC="SQL01ALD", SYSOBJECTID="SQL01ALD", SYSSERVICES="UMTS";
ADD URNCBASIC:SQLID=490, NSAP="H'450551310008501F000000000000000000000000";
ADD UCNOPERATOR:CNOPINDEX=0, MCC="724", MNC="31", OPERATORTYPE=PRIM;
ADD OPC:SPX=0, SPDF=WNF, SPC=16360, NAME="SQL01ALD";
ADD N7DPC:DPX=1, SPDF=WNF, NAME="MSS68ALD", DPCT=IUCS_RANAP;
ADD N7DPC:DPX=2, SPDF=WNF, NAME="MGW04ALD", DPCT=IUCS_ALCAP;
ADD N7DPC:DPX=3, SPDF=WNF, NAME="SQL01ALD";
ADD N7DPC:DPX=4, SPDF=WNF, NAME="SQL01FLZ";
ADD N7DPC:DPX=5, SPDF=WNF, NAME="SQL02ALD";
```

A intenção básica é pegar um campo como referência, por exemplo o campo `SYSDESC="SQL01ALD"` copiar somente o `SQL01ALD` para a base de dados.

Para a lógica de gravar na base de dados, pensei em fazer um loop com `while` pegando o arquivo e gravando no `mysql`.

O X da questão é como pegar o campo que eu quero.

Comment: Pelo que entendi ele quer traduzir dados de uma string(txt) em variáveis no PHP, para depois inserir no banco de dados dele. Não vejo nada de errado com a pergunta e é um problema com que a maioria de nós já se deparou antes. O que eu realmente não entendo é a quantidade absurda de -4 downvotes e nenhum comentário ou ajuda ao OP. Apesar de eu acreditar que as possibilidades são meio amplas e é duplicata, ainda dá para resolver o problema razoavelmente e não há nescessidade de motivar o usuário a **não** fazer mais perguntas porque a comunidade não aceita elas. Dei um upvote para balancear.

Comment: Vai ter que rebolar com a função [`fscanf`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fscanf.php) e talvez expressões regulares :)

Comment: Eu começaria quebrando por vírgula e depois usaria expressão regular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$file = 'file.txt';

$resource = fopen($file, 'r');

$lines = '';
while(!feof($resource)){
    $lines[] = fgets($resource, 4096);
}

$fullVar = true;
$fullVar = $fullVar ? ':' : ''; 

$er = '~([\w%s]+)=("[^"]+"|\w+)~';

$varsFile = array();
foreach ($lines as $k => $value) {
    preg_match_all(sprintf($er, $fullVar), $value, $match);
    foreach ($match[1] as $kk => $result) {
        $varsFile[$k][$match[1][$kk]] = trim($match[2][$kk], '"');
    }
}

// AQUI VOCE TERA AS VARIAZEIS DE CADA LINHA
foreach ($varsFile as $linha => $vars){
    # code...
}
```

Se você quer incluir todo o nome da variável é só manter `$fullVar` como `true`, caso contrario altera para `false` que ele ira capturar a variável reduzida.